# Huge memory leak in Highcharts - Create and destroy lacks memory?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a huge problem while building a small web app for my own home network (some weather data, power consumption etc) with Highcharts.

My use case is, that I have a webapp-running 24/7 which shows me some key data in a simple view, just numbers ;-) 
When I click on one of this numbers/tiles, a detail page with a chart is shown. I've implemented a auto-detail mechanism which scrolls the detail pages every X seconds.

My problem is, that I create Highcharts-Charts on click of the tile, when hiding the tile, the chart is destroyed with ' .highcharts().destroy();', after that the dialog box is destroyed.

---

After about 4-5 hours the browser crashes ('Oh Snap...').
I profiled the memory usage of the website and it looks like that:

[image]

I'm pretty sure, that shouldn't look like that ! As you may see, the 'c' in the below area, is growing hard!

So here my creation of the chart:

```js
if(typeof $(bindTo).highcharts() !== 'undefined'){
      $(bindTo).highcharts().destroy();
}

// get here data with jquery from backend [jquery caching disabled]

var chart = $(bindTo).highcharts({
......
});
```

So here just another detail from the chrome-profiler:

[image]

I just picked one of these blue bars (which means, that this object created here, is still alive at the end of the profiling process [?!] ). It seems that this blue bar consists of this 'c' object, and this belongs to Highcharts.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a known behavior? How can I solve this?
(Yeah maybe I could create every chart just once and just update the data, but that would be my last decission ;-) )

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Okay,

I solved the issue by myself.

After a long time debugging, I found out, that my modal-dialog was detached from the DOM before the destroy-method of Highcharts was used. 
So putting the destroy-method inside a hidden-listener of the modal-dialog did it.

Comment: I am also into same situation, can you describe in detail what is hidden listener , where we can put destroy method?